# Resolution solver in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to build a resolution solver in prolog. What I want to do is given a list named 'Clause' and a list of lists named 'Rest', to find if for an element X in 'Clause' there exists an element neg X in 'Rest' and if this is the case, remove element X from 'Clause' and element neg X from 'Rest'. For example given this input:

```
Clause [neg x,y]
Rest [[x],[neg y]]
```

I want to get:

```
Clause [y]
Rest [neg y]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Any reason why one is a list and the other is a list of list?

Comment: There can be more than one clauses. I take the first clause and compare it with the other clauses.

Comment: That really does not answer the question. Can not the first list be converted into a list of list. IHMO that would make solving this easier.

Comment: Yeah, it can be converted.

Comment: Did you make up this problem or is it a textbook problem?

Comment: I am trying to make a resolution prover. And I tried to think of a way to carry out the resolution step in prolog. So I made it up in a way.

Comment: Are you trying to make something like an automated theorem prover?

Comment: Yes. I want to use resolution for that.

Comment: Are you aware of the code [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/atp/)? I know the code is ML but it implements Prolog with ML.